# React-Router-Dom (TypeScript): location state data returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

While working on a create react app (TypeScript) project and using react-router-dom I was unable to access the data within location.state

within /Edit.tsx I'm able to console.log(location.state) and see all properties within but if I run console.log(location.state.test) it would return undefined, the expected result is 5. What am i missing?

/Relevant packages

```
"@types/react": "^17.0.36",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"typescript": "^4.5.2",
```

/App.tsx

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/edit">
        <Edit />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
```

/Home.tsx

```
import { Route } from "./interface";

const handleEdit = (data: Route) => {
    history.push("/edit", {
      state: { 
        test: 5,
      },
    });
  };
```

/Edit.tsx

```
import { Route } from "./interface"

const Edit = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  let { state } = useLocation<Route>();

  console.log("asdf", state.test);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="contNav">
        <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Back</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

/interface.ts

```
export interface Route {
  test: Number;
}
```

Comment: what do you get calling `console.log(location.state)` in Edit component?

Comment: @Georgy it shows me the state object with the test property and value, but when i try to access it like console.log(location.state.test) i get undefined when i should get 5.

Comment: Try placing the console log in an `useEffect` hook so you're not doing an unintentional side-effect.